# How to pass the value of button to input text field but value should be disappear in text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function getvalue(data)
     {
         document.getElementById('result').value+=data;
     }
     function getequalto()
     {
        var text=document.getElementById('result').value;
        var re=eval(text);
        document.getElementById('result').value=re;
     }
     function plus()
     {
       document.getElementById('plus').style="visibility:hidden";
     }
 </script>
 <input type="text" id="result"><br><br>
 <input type="button" value="1" id="btn" onclick="getvalue(this.value)">
 <input type="button" value="2" id="btn" onclick="getvalue(this.value)">
 <input type="button" value="3" id="btn" onclick="getvalue(this.value)">
 <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="getvalue(this.value) plus()">
 <input type="button" value="=" id="btn" onclick="getequalto()">
```

I want to click on '+' button but this should not be show in input text feild, after that click on '=' button then result should be calculated by this operator.

if i apply visibility hidden method to '+' operator then hidden but not calculate the values.

Comment: id's must be unique.

Comment: [___There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.___](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

Comment: Just remove all the  `ID` attributes and you are good to go...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code it will work perfectly,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function getvalue(data)
     {
         document.getElementById('result').value+=data;
     }
     function getequalto()
     {
        var text=document.getElementById('result').value;
        var re=eval(text);
        document.getElementById('result').value=re;
     }
     function plus()
     {
       document.getElementById('plus').style.visibility="hidden";
     }
 </script>
 <input type="text" id="result"><br><br>
 <input type="button" value="1" id="btn1" onclick="getvalue(this.value)">
 <input type="button" value="2" id="btn2" onclick="getvalue(this.value)">
 <input type="button" value="3" id="btn3" onclick="getvalue(this.value)">
 <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="getvalue(this.value); plus()">
 <input type="button" value="=" id="btn" onclick="getequalto()">
</body>
</html>
```

I have made changes to the dynamic style from `document.getElementById('plus').style="visibility:hidden";` to `document.getElementById('plus').style.visibility="hidden";` which is the working syntax